# Make methods dynamic in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, dynamic

Define a class as follows. I want to call `one_method` dynamically. By default, `wow.one_method` calls the first `one_method`. If I want to change the behavior of the method, just call `redefine`.

I can implement the method as a function type property, but that is not what I want.

If I use the following code directly, it would report errors. Could you  modify it slightly.

```
class Wow

    def one_method
        puts "hello Ruby"
    end

    def redefine(what="none")
        define_method :one_method do 
        puts what
        end
    end
end

wow = Wow.new
wow.redefine("Whatever I want.")
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? What, *precisely* is it that you want to achieve? For example, it is not clear to me whether you want the method redefined for all instances of `Wow` or just for one. Can you provide sample inputs and outputs that demonstrate what you want to achieve? Can you provide a set of rules of what the code is supposed to be doing, including corner cases and edge cases? Also, "it would report errors" is not a precise enough description to help you. *What* errors does it report? Under which circumstances do those errors occur? What do the error messages say? …

Comment: … Which line do those errors refer to? Which method? Also, what is a "function type property"? It is not a concept that exists in the Ruby Language Specification, the RubySpec, the RDoc documentation of the core library and standard libraries, the *Ruby Programming Language* book, or the *Programming Ruby* book, which are usually considered the definitive sources for defining the terms and behaviors of Ruby. Judging by the Google results I am getting, it seems to be a concept from a Python library called "Bokeh", how is that relevant here?

Comment: And one last question: what does this have to do with [tag:dynamic-programming]? There is no divide-and-conquer in your code, no caching, no backtracking, which are usually the main ingredients of a Dynamic Programming Algorithm.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you very much for your detailed consideration. it has nothing to with dynamic-programming, it is a typo. See the answer given by Surya.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that via `class_eval` or `instance_eval`:

```
class Wow

  def one_method
    puts "hello Ruby"
  end

  def redefine(what="none")
    self.class.class_eval do
      define_method :one_method do 
        puts what
      end
    end
  end
end

wow = Wow.new
wow.one_method #=> hello Ruby

wow.redefine("Whatever I want.")
wow.one_method #=> Whatever I want.
```

Reason is that [`define_method`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method) defines instance method on the receiver and is a class's instance method so you'll have to call it on the eigen class of the object that you want to redefine a method on.

Comment: Can you explain how this is superior to using `define_singleton_method` as suggest in the older (admittedly very low-quality) answer?

Comment: @Surya thank you very much. And also Thank Jorg W Mittag

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend achieving your goal in a more canonical way, just redefine the method on the instance itself:

```
class Wow
  def one
    :one
  end
end

w = Wow.new
w.one
#=> :one

def w.one
  :two
end

w.one
#=> :two
```

Drawbacks are:

- your methods lookup table caches will be dropped
- the code is becoming more obscure and hard to debug

Alternatives:

I don't know your real problem, but for your particular question it is better to parameterize your `one_method` method just to receive an argument for `puts`. Also, you can pass a block, so you will receive more grained control over the behavior.